# Why my LEN/ISBLANK functions are not working for my calculated field in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I want to do something really simple. But it seems that it's not. I have a calculated column that say if the column [Ex MRDR] is empty or not. SO I tried this :

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Ex MRDR]),"Empty","Not Empty")
```

But it looks like this does not work :
[image]

And I tried those :

```
=IF([Ex MRDR]="","Empty","Not Empty")
=IF(LEN([Ex MRDR])=0,"Empty","Not Empty")
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Ex MRDR]),[Ex MRDR]=""),"Empty","Not Empty")
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Ex MRDR]),LEN([Ex MRDR])=0),"Empty","Not Empty")
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Ex MRDR]),[Ex MRDR]="",LEN([Ex MRDR])=0),"Empty","Not Empty")
```

Which returns the same thing :

[image]

So, what is wrong with me ? Also, I confirm that there is no spaces in the [Ex MRDR] column.

Here are the configs of the two columns :

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm adding the fact that I created this list through Access, maybe that's the cause. I tried to delete it and reload it with Access but I still have the same error. In another hand, I also tried to recreate manually the same list on SharePoint site and the formula works well...

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter the expression in access table first, then export it to SharePoint:

```
IIf(IsNull([Ex MRDR]),"empty","not empty")
```

[image]

Since number column in access has default value 0, so I change the type of "Ex MRDR" column to short text, and it works well in sharepoint list:

[image]